# Filter values from list in R

Tags: r, list, filter, structure

I want to calculate the mean of a list of named numbers. There are `numeric(0)` values that I first want to remove.  Also, I would like to retrieve which elements of the list contain `numeric(0)` values.

Here is an example how the values could look like:

```
>r["gg",]

$`01_1_er`
   gg 
0.5176445 

$`02_1_er`
   gg 
0.4990959 

$`03_1_er`
   gg 
0.5691489 

$`22_1_er`
numeric(0)

$`23_1_er`
numeric(0)

$`25_1_er`
  gg 
0.386304
```

And here is the result of str:

```
> str(r["gg",])
List of 6
 $ 01_1_er: Named num 0.518
  ..- attr(*, "names")= chr "gg"
 $ 02_1_er: Named num 0.499
  ..- attr(*, "names")= chr "gg"
 $ 03_1_er: Named num 0.569
  ..- attr(*, "names")= chr "gg"
 $ 22_1_er: num(0) 
 $ 23_1_er: num(0) 
 $ 25_1_er: Named num 0.386
  ..- attr(*, "names")= chr "gg"
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: `mean(unlist(r["gg",]))`

Answer (score 42, accepted):

```
## Example list

l <- list(n1=numeric(0), n2="foo", n3=numeric(0), n4=1:5)

## Filter out elements with length 0

l[lapply(l, length) > 0]


$n2
[1] "foo"

$n4
[1] 1 2 3 4 5


## Get names of elements with length 0

names(l)[lapply(l, length) == 0]

[1] "n1" "n3"
```

Comment: I really like this solution. But I have also to unlist as James suggested to calculate the mean. I think a combination of your both answers will work.

Answer (score 25):

Another solution using the [Filter](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/funprog.html) function from base R:

```
mean(unlist(Filter(is.numeric, l)))
```

Comment: The `Filter()` function is great.  This seems like it should be the accepted answer.

Comment: Thanks, R documentation is really confusing there are a lot of filter functions from different packages, and you're not able to find the one that is in base language https://www.rdocumentation.org/search?q=Filter. Maybe there should be documentation just for the language, not every possible library.

Answer (score 2):

Unlisting will pull out just the numeric entries in a single vector which you can call mean on, so try:

```
mean(unlist(r["gg",]))
```

Comment: Further searching lead me to a similar answer. But I do not get the original names and also I do not get the removed elements. I think a combination of your and juba'a answer will solve my problem.