# How to 'Unstack' list in R when some of the entries in the list are not equally repeating like others in list?

Tags: r

This question is an extension of an earlier question ([Filter values from list in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14771029/filter-values-from-list-in-r)). I have a long list similar to the one presented below. One of the names "**issues.fields.customfield_10400**" in the list is repeating lesser number of times compared to all others. Checking of presence/absence of a value for this "name" is one of the task I am trying to handle. NULL value is perfectly fine.

```
DF = structure(list(name = structure(c(7L, 3L, 1L, 6L, 4L, 2L, 5L, 
                                      7L, 3L, 1L, 6L, 4L, 2L, 5L, 7L, 3L, 1L, 6L, 4L, 5L, 7L, 3L, 1L, 
                                      6L, 4L, 5L), .Label = c("issues.fields.created", "issues.fields.customfield_10400", 
                                                              "issues.fields.issuetype.name", "issues.fields.status.name", 
                                                              "issues.fields.summary", "issues.fields.updated", "issues.key"
                                      ), class = "factor"), value = structure(c(18L, 13L, 4L, 4L, 11L, 
                                                                                7L, 10L, 17L, 14L, 3L, 6L, 11L, 7L, 9L, 16L, 13L, 2L, 2L, 11L, 
                                                                                8L, 15L, 14L, 1L, 5L, 11L, 12L), .Label = c("2017-05-05T13:09:12.381-0700", 
                                                                                                                            "2017-06-07T07:03:11.155-0700", "2017-07-26T11:15:03.074-0700", 
                                                                                                                            "2017-08-01T09:00:44.956-0700", "2017-08-14T13:47:21.612-0700", 
                                                                                                                            "2017-08-14T13:47:30.419-0700", "AA1234567", "Acquire replacement files from XYZ", 
                                                                                                                            "Add measurement ", "Ingest changed file location ", "Open", 
                                                                                                                            "Re-classify \"Generic Assays\" (n=24)", "Sub-task", "Task", 
                                                                                                                            "TEST-1030", "TEST-1192", "TEST-1357", "TEST-1358"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("name", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                "value"), row.names = c(NA, 26L), class = "data.frame")

                              name                               value
1                       issues.key                           TEST-1358
2     issues.fields.issuetype.name                            Sub-task
3            issues.fields.created        2017-08-01T09:00:44.956-0700
4            issues.fields.updated        2017-08-01T09:00:44.956-0700
5        issues.fields.status.name                                Open
6  issues.fields.customfield_10400                           AA1234567
7            issues.fields.summary       Ingest changed file location 
8                       issues.key                           TEST-1357
9     issues.fields.issuetype.name                                Task
10           issues.fields.created        2017-07-26T11:15:03.074-0700
11           issues.fields.updated        2017-08-14T13:47:30.419-0700
12       issues.fields.status.name                                Open
13 issues.fields.customfield_10400                           AA1234567
14           issues.fields.summary                    Add measurement 
15                      issues.key                           TEST-1192
16    issues.fields.issuetype.name                            Sub-task
17           issues.fields.created        2017-06-07T07:03:11.155-0700
18           issues.fields.updated        2017-06-07T07:03:11.155-0700
19       issues.fields.status.name                                Open
20           issues.fields.summary  Acquire replacement files from XYZ
21                      issues.key                           TEST-1030
22    issues.fields.issuetype.name                                Task
23           issues.fields.created        2017-05-05T13:09:12.381-0700
24           issues.fields.updated        2017-08-14T13:47:21.612-0700
25       issues.fields.status.name                                Open
26           issues.fields.summary Re-classify "Generic Assays" (n=24)
```

When I unstack the list I get the following error message.

```
Error in (function (..., row.names = NULL, check.rows = FALSE, check.names = TRUE,  : 
  arguments imply differing number of rows:
```

Can someone suggest on how to handle this kind of situation?

I need to create dataframe as given below.

```
res = structure(list(issues.fields.created = structure(c(4L, 3L, 2L, 
                                                   1L), .Label = c("2017-05-05T13:09:12.381-0700", "2017-06-07T07:03:11.155-0700", 
                                                                   "2017-07-26T11:15:03.074-0700", "2017-08-01T09:00:44.956-0700"
                                                   ), class = "factor"), issues.fields.issuetype.name = structure(c(1L, 
                                                                                                                    2L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("Sub-task", "Task"), class = "factor"), 
               issues.fields.status.name = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = "Open", class = "factor"), 
               issues.fields.customfield_10400 = structure(c(2L, 2L, 1L, 
                                                             1L), .Label = c("", "AA1234567"), class = "factor"), issues.fields.summary = structure(c(3L, 
                                                                                                                                                      2L, 1L, 4L), .Label = c("Acquire replacement files from XYZ", 
                                                                                                                                                                              "Add measurement ", "Ingest changed file location", "Re-classify \"Generic Assays\" (n=24)"
                                                                                                                                                      ), class = "factor"), issues.fields.updated = structure(c(2L, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                4L, 1L, 3L), .Label = c("2017-06-07T07:03:11.155-0700", "2017-08-01T09:00:44.956-0700", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        "2017-08-14T13:47:21.612-0700", "2017-08-14T13:47:30.419-0700"
                                                                                                                                                                                                                ), class = "factor"), issues.key = structure(c(4L, 3L, 2L, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               1L), .Label = c("TEST-1030", "TEST-1192", "TEST-1357", "TEST-1358"
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               ), class = "factor")), .Names = c("issues.fields.created", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 "issues.fields.issuetype.name", "issues.fields.status.name", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 "issues.fields.customfield_10400", "issues.fields.summary", "issues.fields.updated", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 "issues.key"), row.names = c(NA, 4L), class = "data.frame")

         issues.fields.created issues.fields.issuetype.name issues.fields.status.name
1 2017-08-01T09:00:44.956-0700                     Sub-task                      Open
2 2017-07-26T11:15:03.074-0700                         Task                      Open
3 2017-06-07T07:03:11.155-0700                     Sub-task                      Open
4 2017-05-05T13:09:12.381-0700                         Task                      Open
  issues.fields.customfield_10400               issues.fields.summary
1                       AA1234567        Ingest changed file location
2                       AA1234567                    Add measurement 
3                                  Acquire replacement files from XYZ
4                                 Re-classify "Generic Assays" (n=24)
         issues.fields.updated issues.key
1 2017-08-01T09:00:44.956-0700  TEST-1358
2 2017-08-14T13:47:30.419-0700  TEST-1357
3 2017-06-07T07:03:11.155-0700  TEST-1192
4 2017-08-14T13:47:21.612-0700  TEST-1030
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the `unstack` function mentioned in the title:

```
us = unstack(DF, value ~ name)
data.frame(lapply(us, `length<-`, max(lengths(us))))
```

This gives

```
         issues.fields.created issues.fields.customfield_10400 issues.fields.issuetype.name issues.fields.status.name
1 2017-08-01T09:00:44.956-0700                       AA1234567                     Sub-task                      Open
2 2017-07-26T11:15:03.074-0700                       AA1234567                         Task                      Open
3 2017-06-07T07:03:11.155-0700                            <NA>                     Sub-task                      Open
4 2017-05-05T13:09:12.381-0700                            <NA>                         Task                      Open
                issues.fields.summary        issues.fields.updated issues.key
1       Ingest changed file location  2017-08-01T09:00:44.956-0700  TEST-1358
2                    Add measurement  2017-08-14T13:47:30.419-0700  TEST-1357
3  Acquire replacement files from XYZ 2017-06-07T07:03:11.155-0700  TEST-1192
4 Re-classify "Generic Assays" (n=24) 2017-08-14T13:47:21.612-0700  TEST-1030
```

The missing values are filled with `NA` -- the standard code in R -- instead of blanks.

Answer (score 2):

```
#Split `DF` by `name` into a list. Keep only the second column for each subgroup
mylist = lapply(split(DF, DF$name), function(a) as.character(a[,2]))

#Obtain the length of the subgroup in the list with most elements
temp = max(lengths(mylist))

#Subset all groups to the `temp`. `sapply` will simplify into matrix
output = as.data.frame(sapply(mylist, function(a) a[1:temp]))
```

Answer (score 1):

This is just changing from 'long' to 'wide' format.  Using `dplyr` and `tidyr`...

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df2 <- df %>% mutate(case=cumsum(name=="issues.key")) %>% 
              spread(key=name, value=value) %>%
              select(-case)

df2
         issues.fields.created issues.fields.customfield_10400 issues.fields.issuetype.name issues.fields.status.name               issues.fields.summary        issues.fields.updated issues.key
1 2017-08-01T09:00:44.956-0700                       AA1234567                     Sub-task                      Open       Ingest changed file location  2017-08-01T09:00:44.956-0700  TEST-1358
2 2017-07-26T11:15:03.074-0700                       AA1234567                         Task                      Open                    Add measurement  2017-08-14T13:47:30.419-0700  TEST-1357
3 2017-06-07T07:03:11.155-0700                            <NA>                     Sub-task                      Open  Acquire replacement files from XYZ 2017-06-07T07:03:11.155-0700  TEST-1192
4 2017-05-05T13:09:12.381-0700                            <NA>                         Task                      Open Re-classify "Generic Assays" (n=24) 2017-08-14T13:47:21.612-0700  TEST-1030
```

Answer (score 1):

With `data.table`'s (or `reshape2`'s) `dcast` function, you can do the following:

```
# create ID variable
dat$id <- cumsum(grepl("TEST-", dat$value, fixed=TRUE))
```

Now, reshape on id by name

```
library(data.table) # or library(reshape2)
dcast(dat, id~name, value.var="value", fill=NA)
```

This returns the desired result below.

```
  id        issues.fields.created issues.fields.customfield_10400 issues.fields.issuetype.name
1  1 2017-08-01T09:00:44.956-0700                       AA1234567                     Sub-task
2  2 2017-07-26T11:15:03.074-0700                       AA1234567                         Task
3  3 2017-06-07T07:03:11.155-0700                            <NA>                     Sub-task
4  4 2017-05-05T13:09:12.381-0700                            <NA>                         Task
  issues.fields.status.name               issues.fields.summary        issues.fields.updated issues.key
1                      Open       Ingest changed file location  2017-08-01T09:00:44.956-0700  TEST-1358
2                      Open                    Add measurement  2017-08-14T13:47:30.419-0700  TEST-1357
3                      Open  Acquire replacement files from XYZ 2017-06-07T07:03:11.155-0700  TEST-1192
4                      Open Re-classify "Generic Assays" (n=24) 2017-08-14T13:47:21.612-0700  TEST-1030
```

Comment: Surprisingly, this seems to work: `dcast(dat, cumsum(name == "issues.key") ~ name)`

Comment: That is neat. I haven't seen a complex formula used in one of these functions. I suppose if such things work in `lm` calls, they should probably work in this context.

Comment: Imo's strategy works for the given example. However, for a long stack of thousands of entries, Frank's strategy works without a hitch.